# Clear Pending intent after use / One Shot

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

I load my webview code inside OnResume. Heres an outline of the code used.

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume(); 
    webView = (WebView)findViewById( R.id.webview );
    //webview options
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        //some stuff here
    }
    });     

    Bundle extras1 = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras1 != null) {
       String theurl =  getIntent().getExtras().getString("url");
                     webView.loadUrl(theurl);   
    } else {
       webView.loadUrl("http://example.com");       
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);
}
```

When the application is launched theres no extras so my default url is loaded.

If the application is launched from a notification then a custom url is loaded.

This functions as expected.

Heres the Pending.Intent code used.

```
    notificationIntent.putExtra("url", url);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    int requestID = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, requestID, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

The pending intent fires and loads the custom url. If i then switch to another application and then switch back to my main application the pending intent gets fired again taking me back to the custom url even if i have already navigated away.

I would like the application to return to the page is was already on after resuming. i.e save the instance state or something.

I thought the FLAG_ONE_SHOT would have taken care of it.

Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer from njzk2 might be sufficient. But just in case you would like to save the most recent url, even if device is restarted, you can use something like this:

Example saving string in shared preferences and retrieve it again anywhere in your app.

```
public class PreferencesData {

    public static void saveString(Context context, String key, String value) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        sharedPrefs.edit().putString(key, value).commit();
    }

    public static String getString(Context context, String key, String defaultValue) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        return sharedPrefs.getString(key, defaultValue);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
PreferencesData.saveString(context, "url", "http://mostrecenturl.com");
// retrieve
String url = PreferencesData.getString(context, "url", "http://mysite.com");
```

Use this to save the string on pause, and recreate it in onCreate, or where ever you need the information

**Edit:**

At the PendingIntent:

```
PreferencesData.saveString(context, "url", url); // url is now persisted
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
int requestID = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, requestID, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

And in your activity in onResume (or onNewIntent if you did move it?) does not matter:

```
            webView = (WebView)findViewById( R.id.webview );
            //webview options
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            //some stuff here
                    }
            });     
            // loads the saved url, or ur default page if it is the very first startup of your app
            String url = PreferencesData.getString(this, "url", "http://mysite.com");
            webView.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: im pretty certain in order for this to work i need to clear the extras from the pending intent although unsure how to.

Comment: Well, the notification must be generated somewhere. At that place simply store the url using this method.

Comment: i couldnt as its a custom url being loaded each time via the pending intent.  If the intent has already fired and i navigate away from the page that it has loaded, onresume it will default back to the last url sent by the pending intent.     if (extras1 != null) {
           String theurl =  getIntent().getExtras().getString("url");
                 webView.loadUrl(theurl);   
       } else {
               webView.loadUrl("http://mysite.com");       
}    if i could clear that bundle after the pending intent has fired it would work i think.

Comment: Forget about the extras .. I will post some example code, moment.

Comment: SmartArse :) looks like it will work a treat, and removes the need for passing the extras etc. Much appreciated.

Comment: Saved me a major headache. im surprised i totally missed that method myself >.<  Thanks again.

Comment: Well you need to know/think about the alternatives before you can choose them :) and no problem, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Your url loading is done in `onResume`, which is called every time you navigate to the app (via any mean. opening the app, back button, notification, recent apps).

You need to put it in onNewIntent only.

And this `webView.loadUrl("http://mysite.com");` should go in `onCreate`, to avoid going back to the home page instead.

Comment: I shall try but moving it out of onResume creates a whole host of other problems. The reason for it being in there is so i can reuse the webview and not have to reload splash screen etc on resum of the application.

Comment: moving url loading from onResume to onNewIntent does not prevent from reusing the webview. in fact, you should be able to do a simple cut-paste without any issue.

Comment: ah ok, i'm still a bit confused, really new to this.  The OnNewIntent that will only be called from the pending intent, so would i not still have to load the url oncreate or onresume in order for it to fire initially?

Comment: in onCreate you probably want to load your default url, yes. That's the case when the application is opened while it was closed.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend just simply moving the code to `onCreate` because the activity could be cleared from memory while you are away and `onCreate` would again send out the intent.

What you should simply do is store a boolean variable [`onSaveInstanceState`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) that indicates whether the intent has already been sent, then in move the code to the `onCreate` and only launch the intent if the boolean is `False`.